# How to colour cells in a particular column based on values in another column (Styling a Dataframe)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am scratching my head trying to work out how to colour the Category column cell values green when Rnum=1 and amber when Rnum=2 (Dataframe below)

Is there a way to do this:

1. Without using the index
2. Using the index value

Many thanks for considering my question, any help would be much appreciated.

| index | Category | Month | MyVal | Rnum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | 1 | 10 | 3 |
| 1 | A | 2 | 20 | 2 |
| 2 | A | 3 | 37 | 1 |
| 3 | B | 1 | 100 | 1 |
| 4 | B | 2 | 22 | 3 |
| 5 | B | 3 | 56 | 2 |
| 6 | C | 1 | 17 | 3 |
| 7 | C | 2 | 99 | 1 |
| 8 | C | 3 | 47 | 2 |

Thanks

Steven